# Relaying multi-part form data through Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form in my HTML. This form takes text inputs and one image:

**HTML**

```
<form class="article_properties_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">             
                        <textarea style="display: none" class="inputNumber" name="pages"></textarea>
                        <p>Image</p>
                        <input style="padding: 0px" type="file" name="image">
                            <p>Subtitle</p>
                            <input type="text" name="subtitle">

                            <p>Text</p>
                            <textarea name="text" rows="4"></textarea>
                            <input id="properties_btn" type="submit" value="Submit/Update">
                        </form>
```

This form will be submitted through Ajax:

**jQuery/Ajax**

```
            $('body').on('submit', '.article_properties_form', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          if ($(this).valid()) {
          $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function() {

                        }   
                    }); 
          }

        });
```

The data will be relayed to PHP:

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["subtitle"], $_POST["pages"], $_POST["text"], $_POST["image"]))
    {
                //Some SQL
    }
```

The form works successfully when I remove the enctype and the input type="image" property. This means that I must be doing something wrong with the image property. I can't figure out how to relay this form through Ajax to PHP with the image property intact. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the `enctype` and to catch the file value, you need to use `$_FILES['image']` to get the "image" value.

On the AJAX code, use this:

```
data: new FormData( this ),
processData: false,
contentType: false
```

Comment: I've tried doing $_FILES["image"] in PHP to get the image value, but it still won't work. I don't think the problem is with my PHP, I think the problem is with the Ajax

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I also have a success: function(data){ Some code }, but the some code isn't initializing for some reason even on form submission...what do you think is wrong?

Comment: The success function is working properly, I just added an alert("!"); and it worked. But it isn't working when I do this: $(this).hide(); I want to hide the form, but I need to use the word "this". When I put $(this).hide(); outside of Ajax, it works properly, but when I put it in inside the success function it doesn't work

Comment: try this way: `$('.article_properties_form').hide()`.

Comment: This will remove all dynamically cloned forms on the page though, I just want that particular form to be removed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117379/discussion-between-muhammad-sumon-molla-selim-and-user2896120).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var fd=new FormData(document.getElementById("YOUR_FORM_ID"));
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"",
data:fd,
enctype:'multipart/form-data',
processData:false,
contentType:false,
success:function(data){console.log(data);},
error:function(err){console.log(err);}
});
```